# sudo apt upgrade command always fails on the first try with "Connection timed out" but resumes after re-trying

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.04

The error being displayed is:

```
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 adapta-gtk-theme all 3.94.0.1-0ubuntu1~bionic1            
  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu/pool/main/a/adapta-gtk-theme/adapta-gtk-theme_3.94.0.1-0ubuntu1~bionic1_all.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I `sudo apt upgrade` my box, sometimes the download of any individual file stops, the download speed indicator in the right side vanishes and then it takes at least a minute or two to display the error above.

This happens most of the times especially when the download size is a bit on the bigger size(>11MB). The **interesting part** is that when I enter the command to upgrade again, it resumes from where it stopped and finishes it successfully. More logs are in the comments below.

Comment: Where is the error? In your log there is none.

Comment: I'm sorry. Please have a look again, I've updated the post with the error.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, I did. Always do so.

Comment: Have you tried changing to a different theme other than **Adapta**?

Comment: This is not an adapta(or any other theme) issue. [Here is the full log](https://pastebin.com/S0LdSnxk).

Comment: do you have a proxy configured for apt?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Hello @Zanna, the edit in the title is not appropriate. It is not just for "one" repository as I stated with my comment on the answer which was posted, which it seems is removed or deleted by the poster. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Tm5w376x) is the log.

Comment: swingcake, you can re-edit your post and I strongly encourage you to do that because the first huge code block has no sign of the issue and should just be deleted. Add the stuff from the pastebin you linked to instead. My edit says the error is for one repository (it's just a different repository every time), not for a particular repository. If you describe your problem more clearly, you are more likely to get an answer. The fact that it works on the second try is maybe the most interesting aspect and should be in the title. Don't let your title be the generic "apt doesn't work"...